# Marionette Application with Multiple Entry Points

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js, marionette

Currently the application that I am building is a single page marionette application with a single entry point. When the user is at "/" I pass a very simple jade document:

```
 body

    header

    section
        div#main

script(src='/javascripts/lib/require.js', data-main='/javascripts/application.js')
```

The only javascript that I am loading to this is my require.js page, and once that's loaded I start things with `Backbone.Marionette.Application()` and thats the only app object I create for the whole app and that takes care of everything.

```
define([
  'zepto', 'marionette', 'router', 'events'],
function ($, Marionette, router, Event) {
    // set up the app instance
    var MyApp = new Backbone.Marionette.Application();

    MyApp.addRegions({
      main: "#main"
    });

    MyApp.addInitializer(function(){

    });

    MyApp.on("initialize:after", function(){
        var newRouter = new router(MyApp);
        Backbone.history.start();
    });

    MyApp.start();
    return MyApp;

});
```

If I have multiple entry points (in other words, multiple html pages created in the server side) for example one for "Classroom", one for "User Profile" one for "Discussion" , does that mean I need separate require.js documents to load for each page and separate `Backbone.Marionette.Application()` objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to otherwise it's too troublesome :) That's the job of Route.

At first, don't start app right away in the app definition. Remove this line

```
MyApp.start();
```

Then, put such command at the footer of your html page, and better after dom ready

```
$(function(){
  MyApp.start();
});
```

The third is the most important. You need to define your routes in App or sub app(better). Here is the code "borrowed" from BBCloneMail

```
BBCloneMail.module("ContactApp", {
  startWithParent: false,
  define: function (ContactApp, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) {

    var Router = Marionette.AppRouter.extend({
      before: function() {
        App.startSubApp("ContactApp", {});
      },

      appRoutes: {
        "contacts": "showContacts"
      }
    });
```

In above case, when visitor enters your app from example.com/contacts, the method `showContacts` will be trigger and that's the start of your arranging page specific logic.

For more about appRouter:
https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.approuter.md

Comment: is this just for "#" urls or would this work for normal urls as well ?

Comment: It depends on your history setting, default is hash. But if you define it with pushState true it works for normal url as well: `Backbone.history.start(pushState: true);`